# Is there a opportunity to prevent default fit behavior in LighningChart JS?

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I want to apply my intervals for X and Y axes in case of fitting. And left the default fitting box on the dragging from left to right.

I want prevent default logic of fitting and create own logic by using of setInterval() with custom values.

Comment: What does the documentation say? I would consider starting there

Comment: I made it with `onSeriesBackgroundMouseDragStart`, `onSeriesBackgroundMouseDragStart`, and `onSeriesBackgroundMouseDragStop `. And similar methods of series. But I thought that it exists built in way like onFit() or smth else. And also I remove event listeners when I leave the page. I use Angular therefore onDestroy I do all methods above but with off prefix.